# How can I provide users option to add search results, with click of button, to database model in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I am a django beginner and am creating a simple app where users can search players from a model and then be given option to add those players as their favorite player, which is stored in a different model. I have created a search view as shown below:

````
```def search(request):
try:
    q = request.GET.get('q')
except:
    q = None
if q:
    Players = Player.objects.filter(First_Name__icontains=q)
    context = {'query': q,
               'Players': Players}
    template = 'home/results.html'
else:
    template = 'home/index.html'
    context = {}
return render(request,template,context)```
````

The search view shows redirects users to home/results.html where results are displayed. I would like for users to be able to click a button next to each of results and add that player to favorites database. I have tried to use Django ModelForms in forms.py as follows:

```
   from django import forms
   from .models import favoritePlayer

   class favoritePlayerForm(forms.ModelForm):
   class Meta:
      model = favoritePlayer
      fields = ['First_Name',]
```

The following is the view function I have wrote to add player into favorites database:

```
def favorite_create_view (request):
form = favoritePlayerForm(request.POST or None)
if form.is_valid():
    form.save()
context = {'form':form}
template = 'home/results.html'
return render(request,template,context)
```

Finally, below is the `results.html` file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Searched for {{ query }}</h1>
  {% for Player in Players %}
  <form method="POST"> {% csrf_token %}
  <a href = "/{{ Player.id }}/">{{ Player.First_Name}}</a>
      {{ form.as_p }}
      <input type="submit" value="Save" />
  </form>
 {% endfor %}
</body>
</html>
```

I cannot get this to work. I would prefer not to use AJAX or Javascript. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
def search(request):
    query = request.GET.get('q', None)
    user = None   #if no 
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        user = request.user
    context =  {"query": query}
    if query is not None:
       Player.objects.create(user=user, query=query)
       Players = Player.objects.search(query=query)

        context['Players '] = Players 
    return render(request, 'home/index.html',context)
```